# OkHttp adding additional data at the start and end of image file while upload action in API call

Tags: java, file-upload, multipartform-data, okhttp

I am trying to perform upload action using OkHttp client. Everything works fine as I can see the image file at the destination but its says "File not supported" Upon comparing with the original file I see some additional header and footer values being added such as "Content Disposition", "Content-Type" and "Content-Length" I think this is corrupting the file. How do I avoid this. Below is my request body and client code

```
 RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
             .addFormDataPart("Image","image1.jpg",RequestBody.create(file, MediaType.parse("image/*"))
             .build();
 OkhttpClient client = new OkhttpClient().newBuilder().proxy(proxy).build();
 Request req = new Request.Builder()
          .url(URL)
          .post(requestBody)
          .addHeader("X-Auth", Auth)
          .buid();
 Response res = client.newCall(req).execute();
```

File here is the image file and I can see it getting uploaded to destination successfully with some additional data appended at the begining and the end of file. How do I avoid this header and footer getting appended. Thanks for the suggestion